# How to clone and remove unselected rows in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, datagridview, clone

I need to remove programmatically all rows in DataGridView except selected rows. First I need to get only selected rows from **CtrlDataGridView1** and put them to **dgv**. I tried this

```
Public ReadOnly Property CtrlDataGridView1Filtered() As DataGridView
    Get
        Dim dgv As New DataGridView
        dgv = CtrlDataGridView1

        For Each dr As DataGridViewRow In CtrlDataGridView1.Rows
            If Not dr.Selected Then
                dgv.Rows.Remove(dr)
            End If
        Next
        Return dgv
    End Get
End Property
```

But It's not OK because CtrlDataGridView1's rows are deleted. But I need remove only dgv's rows.

What should I do? How solve this problem?

Comment: dgv is a reference, CtrlDataGridView1 also. with `dgv = CtrlDataGridView1` you make the two references point to the same object.

Comment: How to clone structure of CtrlDatagridView?. I need to clone Column without rows.

Comment: You can modify the data sources and the DGVs will follow. Only if you are using unbound grids would it seem useful to be copying/deleting rows between grids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clone a DataGridView and then copy the required rows to it such as

```
'CLONE COLUMNS ONLY'
Dim dgv As New DataGridView
For Each dgvCol As DataGridViewColumn In CtrlDataGridView1.Columns
    dgv.Columns.Add(New DataGridViewColumn(dgvCol.CellTemplate))
Next

'COPY SELECTED / UNSELECTED ROWS AS PER YOUR REQUIREMENT'
For Each dr As DataGridViewRow In CtrlDataGridView1.Rows
    If dr.Selected Then
    'OR If Not dr.Selected Then'
        dgv.Rows.Add(dr.Clone)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: dgv.Rows.Add(dr)  is error "Row provided already belongs to a DataGridView control."

Comment: In that case you need to clone the row and then add it to the other gridview. Try `dgv.Rows.Add(dr.Clone)` or create a new Row object and Clone dr to it